# Is there any difference between "already" and "now" when used with the present perfect?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, adverbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *already* and *now* when used with the present perfect? For example:

> I have **already** had five tablets, so I know a thing or two about them.
>
> I have had five tablets **now**, so I know a thing or two about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *already* carries the implication that you expect to have the experience again, or that having had it is a reason for not needing to have it again.

> The pharmacy supplied me with twenty tablets, and I've already taken five.

> I had a lovely holiday in Spain. I've been there five times now.
>
> I think I shall go to Italy next year. I've been to Spain five times already.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm starting to understand the difference but still can't see the difference in my example sentences. Could you please try to clearify it?

Comment: In your example, it doesn't make much difference which you use - which is why I invented some different sentences to show how the two words _could_ have different implications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in connotations.
The first sentence suggests continuing, and the second sentence suggests competition.
"Already" is a tricky one to parse. To borrow Kate's sentence "I've been to Spain five times already", it means very different things when you just told me you're going to Spain or Italy.